# ReferenceError: getElementsById is not defined why?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to set a variable.

```
var fname = getElementsById(fname);
```

A function will then reference this variable on body load

But the console returns ReferenceError: getElementsById is not defined

Why?

Comment: it is getElementById, not plural

Comment: have you defined `getElementsById`?

Comment: use this 'document.getElementById(fname);'

Comment: Of course it's undefined. `ID` is a unique value, unlike `Name`. There's only `getElementById`, but there's `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `document.getElementById('fname');`

so,

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
```

1. add 'document'
2. it should be 'Element' and not 'Elements'
3. fname should be in quotes

refer: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: I realize that and also that I needed to call my script at the end of the document!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
```

You are not using document object to call the method and you have spelling mistake in getElementById.

Comment: Your answer should explain why the OP had their issue and how your code fixes it. Just posting code doesn't do that.

Comment: @RobG Done thanks for your input